# Get average CPU Usage percentage of single process until I kill it in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, cpu, pid

I have a bash script where I would like to get know how much percentage of CPU time a process uses until I kill it in the last line of the script.
I know that I could normally do this via the time -v command, however my process is Erlang/OTP based and by using the time command it only measures the startup process statistics. 
Therefore I'd like to use the process PID I can get easily and use that one to get the CPU time percentage until the end of the script.
Currently I'm using pidstat but it is only giving me statistics for linear time intervals.
I want to measure the exact timeinterval from when the process started until it gets killed.
Peak RAM statistics woul also be nice.
Could you recommend me any command I could use in this case?

This is my bash script:

```
sudo emqx start
sleep 10 
mypid=$(sudo emqx pid)
echo $mypid
sudo pidstat -h -r -u -v -p "$mypid" 5 > $local/server_results/test1/emqxstats_$b.txt &

# process for load testing
# jthreads = amount of publishing users
sleep 5
until sudo ~/Downloads/apache-jmeter-5.2.1/bin/jmeter -n -t $local/testplans/csv.jmx -Jport=$a | grep -m 1 "... end of run"; do : ; done 
sudo emqx stop
kill %!
```

So I want to measure the CPU percentage from the interval between starting mosquitto and until the Apache Jmeter test finished when it reaches the last 2 lines.
Kind regards

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I found the command I was looking after some more research.

```
ps -o pcpu -p $pid
```

this was exactly the command I needed, because it calculates the percentage over the lifetime of the process.